# c++ cli Tracking reference error

Tags: c++-cli, tracking-reference

i can't seem to understand the following error i'm getting when trying to define a tracking reference in my code

```
List<MyClass^>^ myClassList =  nullptr;
DoWork(myClassList);
```

the function signature is:

```
void DoWork([Out] gcroot<List<MyClass^>^> %myClassList);
```

my compilation error is:

[image]

(sorry for the screenshot. SOF doesn't handle well with <> chars inside the error string)

If i remove the tracking reference (remove the '%' char) from the signature it works well.

any ideas?

Comment: gcroot is a native C++ template, its intended use is to allow a native C++ type to store a reference to a managed object.  It wraps an `IntPtr`, safe as a member of a native C++ class.  The compiler complains because passing it by reference requires &, not %.  But realistically you should not use gcroot as an argument at all, DoWork() must be managed code in order to create a List object.  So you'd change the argument type to `List<MyClass^>^%`.  But since the snippet suggests that the caller isn't going to pass a non-null List object, you much prefer `List<MyClass^>^ DoWork()`.

Comment: @HansPassant i totally agree that not using a gcroot is the correct thing to do. however, this is a constrain that we have in our code since our classes are  __declspec(dllexport) . in that case we must use gcroot in all our managed functions :(

Comment: That is useful to allow native code directly call a managed method.  But such native code would not have any idea what gcroot looks like and have no idea how .NET generics works.  It just can't make the call.  You must use a collection type that such code could understand, like a simple array or an std::vector.  Using vector is pretty risky due to the C++ library version dependency, so you are down to a basic C array.  Adding an argument to pass the size is required.  Maybe you ought to be a bit selective about what you expose.